# HttpClient on Windows 10 UWP returns error 405 on request to PHP API

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, dotnet-httpclient

What's up!

I have this problem where a System.Net.Http.HttpClient will return MethodNotAllowed (405) when I try to POST on my Laravel PHP API.

I have tested both an Android app and a Rest Client and the requests worked fine with the route. Below is the code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void loginSequence()
    {
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Classes.WideApplicationClass.getApiURL());
            var values = new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("usuario", txtboxUser.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("senha", txtboxPassword.Text) };
            using (var formUrlContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values))
            {
                var result = await client.PostAsync("obterToken/", formUrlContent);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

                } else {
                    handleError();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the URL is indeed correct:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TToXq.jpg)

Could this error be triggered because i'm not setting specific headers on my client?

Comment: What does the content of the 405 response contain?

Comment: I'd suggest you make sure that your server accepts post request with x-www-form-urlencoded content type.